# jquery.upvote.js only works for first row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to use this jquery package: https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote

However, on my view, the voting only works on the first post, the rest are unclickable.
I've included all necessary files, I'm not sure why it would behave like that.

```
@extends('layouts/default')

@section('content')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/jquery.upvote.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.upvote.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#topic').upvote();
        });
    </script>

    <h1>Subreddit: {{ $subreddit->name }}</h1>

    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4><strong><a href="#"></a></strong></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div id="topic" class="upvote">
                            <a class="upvote"></a>
                            <span class="count">0</span>
                            <a class="downvote"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <p>
                            <a href="#">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                        </p>
                        <p style="color: darkgrey; font-size: 12px;">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>submitted by <a href="#">{{ $post->user->name }}</a>
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i> {{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i> <a href="#">3 Comments</a>
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i> Tags : <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">Snipp</span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">Bootstrap</span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">UI</span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">growth</span></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be unique so use `class` instead in your code. `$('#topic')` will only select the first element which is having the id, so change `id="topic" class="upvote"` to `class="upvote topic"`

```
@extends('layouts/default')

@section('content')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/jquery.upvote.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.upvote.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.topic').upvote();
            //-^---- class selector
        });
    </script>

    <h1>Subreddit: {{ $subreddit->name }}</h1>

    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4><strong><a href="#"></a></strong></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="upvote topic">
                        <!--               --^---- set it as class-->
                            <a 1class="upvote"></a>
                            <span class="count">0</span>
                            <a class="downvote"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <p>
                            <a href="#">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                        </p>
                        <p style="color: darkgrey; font-size: 12px;">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>submitted by <a href="#">{{ $post->user->name }}</a>
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i> {{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i> <a href="#">3 Comments</a>
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i> Tags : <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">Snipp</span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">Bootstrap</span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">UI</span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">growth</span></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

Comment: Now they're all unclickable. I'm using `<div id="topic" class="upvote">` not a class.

Comment: @Halnex : glad to help :)